# pm2 process manager not working

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I install the pm2 using `npm install -g pm2` then when I run my node application using

```
pm2 start app.js
```

nothing is happening. when I run the command in terminal, it just go down another line. No errors or warnings shows in the terminal. I can run the application using nodejs app.js . Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running? Try running it as above and then using `pm2 list`. There's a good chance it's just running in the background.

Comment: Generally when using pm2 "nothing is happening" is the correct expected output that indicates tha pmw **is working perfectly**. PM2 stores all your `console.log()` in a log file that can be viewed by using the `pm2 logs` command. This is a very useful feature which automatically implements logging for you (instead of manually using some logging library like winston or log4js etc.) and also decouples the logging logic completely from your application (which is a good thing)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it happens because of the node.js executable, if you are in Ubuntu install nodejs-legacy to enable the correct "node" executable link, I think pm2 is trying to use this one.

Answer (score 1):

First stop and delete all processes by running `pm2 delete all`. Then run `pm2 start app.js`. Check the logs by running `pm2 logs`

Answer (score 0):

1. use `ps aux|grep node`  check the node is already running?
2. use `pm2 list` check you process is running?
3. check the pid file of you process and do the needful, kill may be.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this behaviour after having a disconnect in ssh connection, while checking the logs using "pm2 log MyAppName". The log process somehow was still opened in background and blocked pm2 insomuch that it didn't react to commands (pm2 log MyAppName, pm2 restart MyAppName...).

The solution was for me to kill the process and everything worked afterwards:

Either use `sudo killall node` or retrieve process id of log command using `ps aux | grep node` and `sudo kill PROCESS_ID`
to kill the process.